# List "filters pane" works fine for text STARTING WITH. But how to filter on text that CONTAIN words?

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, sharepoint-list-filter

In Sharepoint 365 I created a list and by default you can filter with the filter pane.
For instant I have a company colum and a company name in ABC International.
I want to filter for all compies with INTERNATIONAL in the name. That seems not possible because the filter pane on the page only allows you to search for text that "begins with" ...
How to search for items that CONTAINS your text you want to filter on?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to search with some keyword, simply use the list search box, it will do what you want. I will show you both classic and modern experience. 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jerry, you gave me some direction.
Because we are using a communications site, we don't have the search box available as you mentioned in your example. Maybe there is a way to bring that back, but we didn't manage. But in the full list (not the webapp) there is a search box in the upper left corner that search with the CONTAIN principle and you can use wildcards as well.

Answer (score 1):

We use a communication template page.
In the full list page there is a search option on the top left part of the page. That will help.
(Altough not sure why we do miss the search box as @jerry_MSFT explained.

[image]

Comment: Glad to help. You can mark the reply as answer if it works for you.